# Why Java varags method(int[] ...x) accept this "new int[1][1]" 2d array type for argument?

Tags: java, arrays, compilation, variadic-functions

I have method like this.

```
void method(int[] ...x){}
```

and i call method using `method(new int[]{1,2,3,4});`
it's ok. But compiler compile this 2d array type too.

```
method(new int[][]{new int[]{1,2,3},new int[]{4,5,6}});
```

I want know the reason.
*method has 1d array type reference. but compiler accept 2d array type.*

Comment: method is 1d type. argument is 2d type. but comiler accept this.

Comment: This behavior is expected. Are you familiar with `...` notation? What do you think it does? Why do you think your first code shouldn't work (or how do you expect it to work)?

Comment: @UdeeshaInduwara Check my answer. Hope that explains the reason

Comment: And just for the record: you can still accept answers, even for closed questions ;-)

Answer (score 5):

> The underlying type of a variadic method `function(Object... args)` is `function(Object[] args)`

So an `Object...` is only a syntactic sugar for an `Object[]`.

So the method `void method(int[] ...x){}` in your case having 1D array as parameter should be read as `void method(int[][] x){}` having 2D array as parameter

Hence it compiles and will give no runtime error also.

Answer (score 3):

Simple: because the type `Whatever ... varargs` is (almost) the same as `Whatever[] varargs`. Expect that the compiler does some magic for you in places where the method is invoked (like creating the required array object for you).

In other words: you declare an array of varargs of int, which in essence is nothing else but an array of array of int.

Beyond that: don't do that. Do **not** use array of varargs.